# Plot a graph using dataframe with specific conditions

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2, dplyr

I have a dataframe which looks like:

```
ID    Char                       Var         epoch
1     sr.r/t & (ted: 15--) sr    a-rt        1501569011720
1     sr.r/t & (ted: 15--) sr    a-er        1501569011820
1     sr.r/t & (ted: 15--) sr    a-er        1501569011870
2     sy.w/f & (ted: *18-) /s    a-ge        1501569012945
2     sy.w/f & (ted: *18-) /s    a-ge        1501569012995
2     sy.w/f & (ted: *18-) /s    b-we        1501569013945
3     sr.r/t & (ted: 19:15)ser   e-we        1501569013945
```

First dataframe:

```
ID    Char                       Var         epoch
1     sr.r/t & (ted: 15--) sr    a-rt        1501569011720
1     sr.r/t & (ted: 15--) sr    a-er        1501569011820
2     sy.w/f & (ted: *18-) /s    a-ge        1501569012945
2     sy.w/f & (ted: *18-) /s    b-we        1501569013945
```

The first dataframe would be derived from datafram, where string in `Char` is same for the particular `ID` but `Var` is different.

Based on the first dataframe, i want to plot a graph which show me count of `Char` on x axis with the interval of Minute on y axis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess epoch = minutes. Then :

```
library(tidyverse)
# for each Char compute time laps
a.plot <- first_dataframe %>% 
   group_by(Char) %>% 
   summarise(minutes=min(epoch)-max(epoch))

# plot the results as a barplot
ggplot(a.plot,aes(x=Char,y=minutes))+geom_bar(stat="identity")
```

Comment: Rosewic Thanks...will you please suggest me how to subset first dataframe.

Comment: It's not really clear in your question. So dataframe contains lines with same ID, same Char and same Var but different epochs. What will be the rule to discard duplicate lines then. Please clarify your questions by giving test input and test output for each dataframe.

Comment: Rosewich the rule would be that for each unique `ID` if there is same string in `Char` with different `Var` than extract it into first dataframe with as it is timestamp.

Comment: give an example. Not clear for me which duplicate entry to discard.

Comment: Rosewich I have updated the question, in first dataframe there are only those rows which has same string in `Char` but `Var` is different.